# An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container with Mongoose Schema Typescript

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have the following for a schema validator for MongoDB:{

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(async function (email: string) {
  const count = await User.count({ email, _id: { $ne: this._id } })
  return !count
}, 'Email already exists')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
User.ts(171, 35): An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.
```

This is defined in my `User.ts` file.  Everything works exactly as expected but this Typescript error is blocking CI from continuing.  Is there anyway to get around this (no pun intended).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(async function (this:any, email: string) {
  const count = await User.count({ email, _id: { $ne: this._id } })
  return !count
}, 'Email already exists')
```

You can use your type instead of "any".

And the link to the docu: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters

Comment: This works!  Before you answered I actually used a plugin that changed the default `unique` field behavior to show as normal validation errors so that I can put the validation error message directly into the schema itself.